# Отображение на одной плоскости двух графиков QWT

Tags: c++, qt

Что нужно сделать чтобы получить два графика на плоскости QWT?
Вот мой код

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    points << QPointF( 0.1 * i, 0.1 * i); 
}
curve->setSamples( points ); 
curve->attach( ui->Qwt_Widget );
```

Что нужно добавить в этот код чтобы отобразить второй график на плоскости?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скопитырено [отсюда](https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_plot.html)

```
#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>
QwtPlot *myPlot = new QwtPlot( "Две кривые", parent );
// добавление кривых
QwtPlotCurve *curve1 = new QwtPlotCurve( "Кривая 1" );
QwtPlotCurve *curve2 = new QwtPlotCurve( "Кривая 2" );
// добавление данных к кривым
curve1->setData( ... );
curve2->setData( ... );
curve1->attach( myPlot );
curve2->attach( myPlot );
// Последнее, обновление плоскости вывода данных
myPlot->replot();
```